# R Shiny: "global" variable for all functions in server.R

Tags: r, scope, shiny

I put global in quotes because I don't want it to be accessible by ui.R, just accessible throughout every function in server.R. Here's what I mean:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  df <- NULL
  in_data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)     
    else df <<- read.csv(inFile$datapath, as.is=TRUE)  
    return(NULL)
   })
  output$frame <- renderTable({
    df
  })
})

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
   sidebarPanel(fileInput("file1", "Upload a file:",
                           accept = c('.csv','text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain'),
                           multiple = F),),
   mainPanel(tableOutput("frame"))
))
```

I have `df` defined at the beginning of the shinyServer function, and try to change its global value in `in_data()` with the `<<-` assignment. But `df` never changes its `NULL` assignment (so the output in `output$frame` is still `NULL`). Is there any way to change the overall value of `df` within a function in shinyServer? I want to then use `df` as the uploaded data frame throughout all of my functions in server.R so that I only have to call `input$file` once.

I looked at [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/how-to-read-file-from-user-in-shiny-and-assign-it-to-a-variable-in-global-r) post, but when I tried something similar, and error was thrown that envir=.GlobalENV wasn't found. The overall goal is to only call `input$file` once and use the variable the data is stored in instead of repeatedly calling `in_data()`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use reactive values [Reactive values](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/reactiveValues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea to use reactive is the right direction; however you didn't do it quite right. I just added one line and it is working:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  df <- NULL
  in_data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)     
    else df <<- read.csv(inFile$datapath, as.is=TRUE)  
    return(NULL)
  })
  output$frame <- renderTable({
    call.me = in_data()   ## YOU JUST ADD THIS LINE. 
    df
 })
})
```

Why? Because a reactive object is very similar to a function, which gets executed only when you call it. Thus the 'standard' way of your code should be:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  in_data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)     
    else read.csv(inFile$datapath, as.is=TRUE)  
  })
  output$frame <- renderTable({
    in_data()
  })
})
```