# Shiny: observe change in global variable

Tags: r, scope, shiny, global, shiny-reactivity

I am making a very simple game in Shiny. Basically every player plays in their own session, but they share 1 global variable to keep track of the scores of each player.

I think I'm succeeding having sessions update the global 'scores' variable, but for some (probably dumb) reason I cannot get the global variable to act as a reactive value (i.e. automatically triggering updateActionButton). Minimal code below:

working example:

```
score <- c(100) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("increase_score", label = " increase score player 1 "),
    verbatimTextOutput("show_score_p1")
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$increase_score,{
    score[1] <- score[1]+10
  })
  output$show_score_p1 <- renderText({paste(score[1])})  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I tried a couple of methods to try and make my global 'score' to be reactive, i.e. makeReactiveBinding(score), but to no avail. Any ideas? Definitely feels like I'm missing something super-obvious

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482434/r-shiny-global-variable-for-all-functions-in-server-r 

See also: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Comment: I don't think its a comment, as the question you refer to does not involve updating a global variable accross sessions

Answer (score 2):

Use can use a helpful function called `reactiveValues`

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("increase_score", label = " increase score player 1 "),
    verbatimTextOutput("show_score_p1")
  )
)

score<-reactiveValues(a=100)
# Server logic
server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$increase_score,{
    score$a <- score$a+10
  })
  output$show_score_p1 <- renderText({
    score$a
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your reply! I do not think 'reactiveValues' will help here, as this will simply create a session-dependent (reactive) copy of my global variable right? My aim is that once one session updates the 'score' variable, all other sessions should be able to see it as well

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your point. If you want the `score` reactive with multiple session, you just need to move `score<-reactiveValues(a=100)` out to `server`. See the revised code, it work perfectly with multiple session. One session click the button, all the session will see `score` change.