# Shiny react to change in global variable

Tags: r, shiny

I've been struggling on a Shiny problem for quite a while and wonder if somebody has a suggestion.
I have a Shiny app in which I store some data in a global variable.
I would need to update the value of some output text when the value of the global variable changes.
I've seen this discussion [Shiny: observe change in global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52282940/shiny-observe-change-in-global-variable) but just to be clear, I would need the opposite.
You may wonder why I need this.
The value of the global variable depends on some data received from an SQL query. 
So the question is: is it possible to create an output text element that reacts as soon as the value of the global variable changes?
Many thanks

Comment: Without a minimal, complete, reproducible example it is very difficult to answer this. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and revise your question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957871/shiny-global-reactive-dataset/52978592#52978592) might be of interest.